# Built in audio not working Kubuntu

Tags: linux, audio

I have been using Kubuntu 18.04 for the past few months when i switched my audio profile. Now it fails to play audio, and any attempt to reset it made it show "dummy output" on the audio panel, and I can't seem to find any way to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did it work before you switched profiles?

Comment: Yes, but I was playing around with the profiles and couldn't get back

Comment: Could you explain which profile was selected before the problem started? What profile did you choose that made it stop working? The thing is that just saying that you "switched audio profiles" without telling us which audio profiles you selected, and how you might have gone about trying to set it back and to which one, your question is likely lacking the critical information necessary for us to fully understand the problem and solve it. The more specific and precise information you can give us, the better the chance we can get you a good answer.

Comment: I think it was off at the start, I didn't memorize the profiles. It took me a few to realize it was broken.